# What does it mean "to drive something into a ditch"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I got an email from an English native speaker.
The context is that a known situation is not going as expected.

The problem is ongoing, and at some point, the person responsible (P1) says to the people they report to (P2):

> P1: That was unexpected. I know the problems are mounting, but we'll fix them.
> P2: That's okay. You are doing a great job. I'd have driven this whole situation into a ditch long ago.

How should one read "I'd have driven this whole situation into a ditch long ago"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a native English speaker quite familiar with the term, I can say that it's a straightforward metaphor for driving off the edge of a road.  Not all roads are built this way, but it's relatively common for there to be ditches on the sides of the road that prevent cars that go off the road from continuing on to cause damage to the surroundings.  Typically, a car that's done this cannot continue on under its own power; it will require a tow.

Someone who drives into a ditch has -- through inattention or incompetence -- strayed from the main path and likely gotten stuck.  This is not nearly as dangerous as having been involved in a crash, but it's a serious inconvenience.

In the example, P2 is saying simply that s/he would have done worse, gotten them into trouble from which it would be difficult to extricate themselves.

Answer (score 6):

Also speaking as a native English speaker, when you've driven something into a ditch, this essentially means that you've messed something up so thoroughly that it can no longer be fixed.

Compare this to driving a car on the road. If you steer poorly and start to go off the road, the situation is still salvageable. You can turn the steering wheel and easily be back on track. However, if you drive off the road and straight into a ditch, there's no way that you can continue to drive the car from the ditch back onto the road. The ditch is a dead end, and you're pretty much at a point of no return.

Answer (score 0):

It's essentially a variant of the phrase "to drive something into the ground." [TfD defines that as follows:](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/drive+(something)+into+the+ground)

> To manage or maintain something very poorly, resulting in its destruction, failure, or loss of functionality.

Comment: I don’t think that’s the least bit related.